# apt-get returns error "debconf: Perl may be unconfigured" / how do I actually understand linux errors

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get, raspberry-pi

Ahoy there.

So I have Debian installed on my raspberry pi, and everything has been going great, but somewhere along the line my apt-get broke.  Now whenever i try to install or remove anything, it fails and returns errors messages like this one:

```
debconf: Perl may be unconfigured (Quantifier follows nothing in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/* <-- HERE     nostdio.h
 *
 *    Copyright (C) 1996, 2000, 2001, 2005, by Larry Wall and others
 *
 *    You may distribute under the terms of either the GNU General Public
 *    License or the Artistic License, as specified in the README file.
 *
 */ at /usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/Handle.pm line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/Handle.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/Seekable.pm line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/Seekable.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/File.pm line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/File.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl/5.10/FileHandle.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 1) line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 1) line 3.
) -- aborting
```

Perl seems to be installed and functioning normally.  Where else might I look for clues, and how might I repair my apt-get installation?

I guess this hints at a larger issue too: I consider myself a competent web programmer, with about 10 years of front end and backend experience, but linux library/compilation errors still feel like I'm reading Etruscan.  Are there any good docs on diagnosing common types of  compilation/installation errors in Linux so that I can feel less like I'm typing in a magic spell I found on Google, and more like I actually am understanding my solutions?

Thank you, Internet.

Comment: All tools are more or less different in the details but most share some heritage with tools from the olden days. Typically you need to be very picky when reading an error report like this one and go to the `perl` documentation to see what `require` means. If I were to guess, you've managed to remove some (central) module in your `perl` installation which generates this error.

Answer (score 1):

You might try:

```
dpkg --configure -a
```